# If the cell contains the word "xxx" then do "xxx"

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I am working on a spreadsheet and I am trying to create a script, but I don't know how to do this:
I want to write an if statement where if the last row of column B contains the word, let's say "flower", then do something.
Can you please help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Search engines are your friend. Before asking a question, you should really do some proper research https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en

Comment: @JordanRhea so the exact same link i posted already?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of how you can use Google Scripts to do an if statement. Paste this into the script editor, then run it. If A1 has the value 1, then it will change B2 to "Yay!", otherwise B2 will be "Really?!"

```
function myFunction() 
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

    var range = sheet.getRange("A1"); //gets a cell to test the value of

    if (range.getValue == 1)
    {
        sheet.getRange("B2").setValue("Yay!") //sets the value of B2 if true
    }
    else
    {
        sheet.getRange("B2").setValue("Really?!") //sets the value of B2 if false
    }
```

}

You can also add in `else if` if you want to add additional conditions, then whatever manipulation or function you want to do needs to inside the brackets